# Swift arguments not allowed when function is assigned to a variable?

Tags: swift, arguments

Swift 3 requires that all argument labels be included in a function call by default. Yet when a function is assigned to a variable (or constant), and the variable passes arguments, no argument labels are necessary—or even allowed.

For example, for a function with two Int parameters (`int1` and `int2`) assigned to a variable called `varName`:

```
varName (1, 5) // will work, but
varName (int1: 1, int2: 5) //produces an error for extraneous argument labels.
```

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. What is the rationale for not requiring argument labels here? (I can’t find any documentation on this.)

Comment: It would help if you updated your question with complete examples demonstrating your question.

Comment: I think you'll want to read this: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0111-remove-arg-label-type-significance.md

Comment: @jtbandes Yes, that article squarely answered my question. Thank you so much.

Comment: @rmaddy I wrote up a test case in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. See [SE-0111 - Remove type system significance of function argument labels](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0111-remove-arg-label-type-significance.md).

Example:

```
func foo(bar: Int, baz: String) {
    print(bar, baz)
}

foo(bar: 123, baz: "abc") // Valid, prints: 123 abc

let x = foo //Inferred type: (Int, String) -> Void
x(123, "abc") // Valid, prints: 123 abc

let y: (bar: Int, baz: String) -> Void = foo // Invalid
    // ERROR at line 10, col 9: function types cannot have argument label 'bar'; use '_' instead
    // let y: (bar: Int, baz: String) -> Void
    //         ^
    //         _ 
    // ERROR at line 10, col 19: function types cannot have argument label 'baz'; use '_' instead
    // let y: (bar: Int, baz: String) -> Void
    //                   ^
    //                   _ 
y(bar: 123, baz: "abc") // Invalid
    // ERROR at line 19, col 2: extraneous argument labels 'bar:baz:' in call
    // y(bar: 123, baz: "abc") // 123 abc
    //  ^~~~~~     ~~~~~
```